How to keep the menu selected with EasyAdmin in a custom template
I am using EasyAdmin with Symfony. I have created a custom template to manage an Entity. We arrive at this template from the menu created for this purpose from DashboardController:
public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
{
    yield MenuItem::subMenu('Organización', 'fa fa-sitemap')->setSubItems([
        MenuItem::linkToRoute('Usuarios', 'fa fa-users', 'admin_users'),
        MenuItem::linkToRoute('Cargos', 'fa fa-user-shield', 'admin_position')
    \]);
}

admin_users and admin_position are the paths by which my controller generates the custom template.
When the "Usuarios" menu is selected, the template is generated correctly with a personalized list of users, and on the left, the "Usuarios" menu is selected.
In the user list I have added a sorting system to order the records based on the selected column.
To select each column I reproduce the corresponding links just like the link that the menu has, and I also add the sorting parameters so that the Controller returns the correct list
<a href="admin?routeName=admin_members&routeParams%5Bservice%5D={{service}}&routeParams%5Boffset%5D={{offset}}&routeParams%5BorderBy%5D={{columnsOrder[loop.index0]}}&routeParams%5BorderDirection%5D={{newOrderDirection}}">

Although the record sorting works fine, on the left side, the menu no longer appears selected. And I don't really understand why
I have tried adding other elements that EasyAdmin generates in each menu, such as:
target="_self" referrerpolicy="origin-when-cross-origin"
But, obviously, they do not affect the behavior.
Would anyone know how to help me?
